# Read assets file outside library android

Tags: android, assets, android-library

I'm creating an Android library and I want developers to be able to provide a configuration file in their Android project.

Is there any way to find and read this file(having a specific name) without having the context of the android project?

Or is there a standard procedure for library configuration files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to find and read this file(having a specific name) without having the context of the android project?

No, assuming that by "the context of the android project", you mean a `Context`.

> Or is there a standard procedure for library configuration files?

Usually, that would be some form of resource, or perhaps an asset. Or nothing at all, instead going with some sort of builder API that the app developer would call.

If you do not want to deal with `Context`, accept an `InputStream` as a parameter to your constructor or initialization method. That gives the app developer the flexibility to use raw resources, assets, internal storage, external storage, or other possible places to have this configuration file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably pass the Context object to the library. My initial idea was to automatically find the file and configure the library without any developer interaction. iirc Spring and Hibernate can find their configuration files if they are placed in the correct location with a standard name.

Comment: @Gert-Jan: I would recommend that you have other options than that. As it stands, your approach would prevent other libraries from using your library, as everything gets merged together in an Android APK, and there can only be one magic configuration file at a magic place.